# Can I update a user's attributes with a form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there a way i can use a form to update a user's points in rails with a simple form that takes in the name and the points I want to append?

Heres the link to the app i made : [enter link description here](https://shielded-ocean-4668.herokuapp.com/)

my view for the index is :

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">Listing Students</h1>
    <div class ="jumbotron">
      <table class="table table-hover">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Points</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
            <% @users.each do |user| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= user.name %></td>
                <td><%= user.points %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
              </tr>
           <% end %>
        </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
   <br>
  <%= link_to 'New Student',  new_user_path, class:'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

I tried using the code in my edit page :

```
<div class="container">
<div class=" text-center">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class= "well well-lg">
                <%= render 'form' %>
                <%= link_to 'Back', users_path, class:"back"  %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to render the form in the index but it gives me an error of @user can not be nill

I simply need to update the users points in the index page , it would be great if i can greate a modal to appear and then type in the name and edit it. Ive been working on this for hours and seem to update it .

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) or [form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for). Or you could do inplace editing. Your question is not very precise as to what exactly you need.

---

UPDATE 1:

Assuming that you have added simple_form gem to the gemfile, and that you have something like this in the routes.rb : `resources :users`, then edit view of the UsersController could look something like this:

```
#in controller
def edit
  @user = User.find(params['id'])
end
```

And the view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :points %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Please try it and let me know if it works for you (the edit view; in order to persist, you will need and update action as well).

Comment: bosskovic i tried using  form_for @user and it gave me an error , and when i try to render the edit page it also givves me and errir

Comment: unfortunately it didnt even show up right , i got an error " undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass " i did install simple_form

Comment: What are you calling the model_name on? Please include all code for the edit action, edit view and any partials you render there.

Answer (score 0):

Add a div on index page to open modal popup:

```
<div class='modal_popup>
</div>
```

For updating name and points of user on index page, you have to change edit link like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user), remote: true %>
```

Controller changes:

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

_modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <%= form_for @user, remote: true do |f| %>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <%= f.text_field :name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :points %>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <%= f.submit 'Update', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

edit.js.erb

```
$('.modal_popup').html("<%= j(render partial: '/users/modal') %>");
$('.modal').show();
```

After updating user in update.js.erb add below lines of code:

```
$('.modal').hide();
window.location.reload();
```

Hope this may help..